# Django - Access Context Dictionary Before Template

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-context

I'm hoping to use a context processor or middleware to modify the values of the dictionary passed to render_to_response prior to the actual rendering.  I have a messaging schema I'm trying to implement that would populate a message list based on the existence of a type of user that I'd like to search the context for prior to the rendering of the template.

Example:

```
def myview(...):
    ...
    return render_to_response('template.html',
        {'variable': variable},
    )
```

and I'd like to be able to add additional information to the context on the existence of 'variable'.

How can I access 'variable' after my view defines it but before it gets to the template so that I can further modify the context?

Comment: How can I access 'variable' after my view defines it but before it gets to the template so that I can further modify the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/):

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def myview(...):
    ...
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'template.html', 
        {'variable': variable},
    )

def my_view_wrapper(...):
    response = my_view(...)
    variable = response.context_data['variable']
    if variable == 'foo':
        response.context_data['variable_is_foo'] = True
    return response
```

Comment: This was the response to my question :)  The function my_view_wrapper from the comment I implemented as a process_template_response() in my middleware, which then gains access to response.context_data, which has the data I required.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. If you have supplied just a *little* bit more code in your example the answer might have bit you.

```
# first build your context, including all of the context_processors in your settings.py
context = RequestContext(request, <some dict values>)
# do something with your Context here
return render_to_response('template.html', context)
```

**Update to comment:**

The result of a `render_to_response()` is an HTTPResponse object containing a template rendered against a Context. That object does not (to my knowledge) have a context associated with it. I suppose you could save the result of `render_to_response()` in a variable and then access the Context you passed it, but I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.

Did you *modify* the Context during rendering? If so you may find that the information is not there any longer because the Context has a scope stack which is pushed/popped during template processing.

Comment: I don't see how my settings.py will know which user type is being accessed on page load.  I want different information to be loaded based on what type of user is being accessed, however this is a universal action, so it shouldn't need to be done in each view.  Is there a way to access the context/view-generated-dictionary AFTER the render_to_response() is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictonary for the context:

```
def myview(...):
    c = dict()
    c["variable"] = value
    ...
     do some stuff
    ...
    return render_to_response('template.html',c)
```

Maybe the [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: In a middleware process_response I used RequestContext(response) and it was missing all of the view-defined variables, like c["variable"] in your response.  Also, I want it automated outside of the view if possible, since I'll be loading these variables in multiple locations.  Sorry if I haven't been 100% clear :)